# Installing Confluent Plugins on Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, apache-kafka-connect, jenkins-x

Our team is developing Kafka Connect Source Connector-plugins.

Do you have any ideas on how to install/upgrade the plugins? How is the flow (git -> Jenkins -> running Source Connector) supposed to look on-prem?

We use Confluent on Kubernetes which complicates things further.

PS. We are required by law to not use cloud solutions.

Comment: Are you talking about Kafka Connect plugins?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yeah! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

To store custom connectors, use Nexus, Artifactory, S3, or some plain HTTP/file server.

If you are using Kubernetes, then you probably have a release policy around your Docker images.

Therefore, you can extend the Confluent Connect Docker images by adding additional `RUN` statements to the Dockerfile, then build and tag your images with Jenkins, and upgrade your Kubernetes services to use the new image tag.

---

The answer I would give for a bare-metal (or cloud) installation of managing Kafka Connect would be to use Ansible or other orchestration tool to push out the new files, and restart the services